# Nodejs Socket io on regexp match

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, socket.io

Im trying out Node and Socket IO, and im trying to match routes in similar way node does it
e.g

```
app.get("controller/action/somevar", callback);
```

however using regex in socket event matching seems not to work. Is there a way to match regex event, or at least match a wildcard "*"

I tried this.

```
socket.on(/.+/gi, function (data) {
socket.emit('set_time', { time: '13:32'});
});
```

I would like to intercept all events coming from some controllers or containing some variables.

ps: i found a blog which mentioned that there is no way to match regex events, but that was 2 years ago, perhaps things have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sockets inherit from [`EventEmitter`](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter) so only support regularly named events (no fancy stuff like wildcards or regexes).

A [somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468110/node-js-minimal-function-for-parsing-route) discusses some options to implement an Express-like routing layer on top of `socket.io`, but [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19473408/893780) isn't a drop in replacement and requires both client and server code rewrites.

A rather different approach, but perhaps applicable in your situation, is taken by the [`sockatron`](https://npmjs.org/package/socketron) module.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I spent some time on tracing the socket io source to find out where the socket.on function is inherited and what it does. 
I traced it back to EventEmitter, as you mentioned, and i started to write something similar to what is in the link you posted. 

Ill go through that sample and will probably mark this answer as accepted later.

Comment: @RainerPlumer if your code is worth sharing, consider making it an NPM package :)